# Flask OS environment Variables - Change per view called?

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have google credentials that are saved as OS environment variables. I would like to work with more than one project credential depending on the view that is called. I have implemented as shown below

```
@app.route('/project/one', methods=['POST'])
def project_one():
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path/to/project/one/json/file"
    #do stuff authenticated by project one credentials

@app.route('/project/two', methods=['POST'])
def project_two():
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/path/to/prject/two/json/file"
    #do stuff authenticated by project two credentials
```

When I test this individually, the two endpoints call to the correct google project and I get the expected results.

My worry is in high traffic situation where the two endpoints are called concurrently, am I likely to get errors from the os variable being set in two places and if so which approach should I set for this.

I do not have control on the name of the variable so can't give it different names.

Thanks for your answers in advance

Comment: Which GCP product are you using?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza am using Dialogflow

Comment: Please provide more details. Why do you want to use to credentials to call to two different projects, any scenario? What is the specific situation when calling `proj1` different then `proj2`? What did you try?
If the env variable is set to `proj1` and the call is to `proj2` there will be possible a 403 error. As you have set the variables within a function when are these function called? Is it possible for you to provide more code?

Comment: I am using one app to serve two different dialogflow agents to two different user facing channels using the dialogflow python client library.

Comment: In this setup you are using 1 agent per project? Are you using any conditions to call specific agent? If so, could you try to use env variable in the condition? The env variable you are using is to access specific agent?